# Studying uniform convergence of function sequence $f_n=\frac{n}{n^2+x^2}$ and $f_n=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I tried proving that the following function sequences converge uniformly but unfortunately I don't really have a clue how to do it properly and formally correct and I can't get any further. We have defined unfirom convergence as this:

$∀ \epsilon>0 \ ∃\ N \in \mathbb{N}: d_\infty (f_n, f) ≤ \epsilon \ ∀n\ ≥N$

where $d_\infty$ is the supremum-metric.

> a) $$f_n=\frac{n}{n^2+x^2}$ $\ \mathbb{D} = \mathbb{R}$$
>   b) $$f_n=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ $\ \mathbb{D} = [0, \infty)$$

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you have any clue what functions these sequences should converge to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one see that

$$\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\frac{n}{n^2+x^2} =\frac1n \to 0~~~\mbox{uniformly}$$

For the second one the convergence cannot be uniform

Indeed the point-wise convergence shows that

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n+1} = f(x)= \begin{cases}1&x> 1\\
\frac12 &x=1\\0&x> 1\end{cases}$$
**the limit $f$ is clearly not continuous so the convergence cannot be uniform.**
it is only true on $[a,\infty)$ with $a>1$ or on $(0,b]$ with $b<1$

$$\sup_{x\ge a}|f_n(x) -1|=\sup_{x\ge a}\frac{1}{x^n+1} =\frac{1}{a^n+1}  \to 0~~~\mbox{uniformly}$$

Whereas $$\sup_{x\ge 1}|f_n(x) -1|=\sup_{x\ge 1}\frac{1}{x^n+1}  =\frac12 \not\to 0~~~$$

Comment: Why in $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x) -1|$ is $1$ subtracted, $f_n$ does not converge to $1$ pointwise

Comment: @clark see the edit

Comment: For $0 \leq x<1$ shouldn't $f_n$ converge to zero?

Comment: @clark I think 1 is correct but it should be 1/2 for x = 1 I think

Comment: @michael3231 When $0<x<1$, then $x^n\rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^n}\rightarrow 1$, so $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @clark thanks I fixed everything now

Comment: @michael3231 see the edit